# c# log4net not logging line number of exception

Tags: c#, log4net

In my local code base, my log file logs the exact line number where the exception took place.  However, my boss just sent me a log file from a client, and I don't see a single line number in the log.  Is there a setting I am missing to log the line number for a deployed application?

Comment: Btw you can see line numbers in your code editor, e.g. vim, notepad++ etc...

Comment: or even `cat -n <log-file>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want line numbers in your logged stack trace you have to deploy the matching `.pdb` files. Even then the line numbers might not match the source code if you compiled with `Optimize code` enabled (recommended for prod builds).

Comment: Saved me 2 weeks of headaches with the CMS Umbraco's logging. Which utilises Log4Net in older versions yet nobody could tell me this fact!

Answer (score 0):

Note that as well as having a `.pdb` file - it must be the correct one.
If it's a stale/old version of the file, the framework detects that and falls back to  quietly just not logging the line numbers.